# run class file as separate process from java code

Tags: java, class, process, runtime.exec

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java E:/workspace/JNIProgram/src/JNIProgram.class");
}
```

so I have this code and am trying to run the JNIProgram.class file however the program gets terminated instantly without doing its job (which is to create a new txt file and write to it)

So what am I doing wrong

Comment: Also check the tips in the [runtime.exec info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `java` command expects a Java **class name**, not a filename.

So the command `java E:/workspace/JNIProgram/src/JNIProgram.class` is wrong. If you try this manually from a command prompt window you'll get an error message.

The command should be something like this:

```
java -cp E:\workspace\JNIProgram\src JNIProgram
```

Note: What's after the `-cp` option is the classpath, and after that the fully-qualified class name (which is just `JNIProgram`, if the class is not in a package).

First make sure that you can run the command manually from the command line before you make it work from another Java program.