# invoking class file from java program

Tags: java, runtime.exec

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614112/run-class-file-as-separate-process-from-java-code)
This question had an issue with filename vs classpath.
I am using classpath in my program and yet was not getting the output.

I searched a lot through various posts, but I was unable to resolve my error.
I have a class file in my D: The file just prints "hello world".

When I run it through command prompt as:

```
java -cp D:/ Test
```

it works fine.

But when I run the same inside a main method of another java program as:

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -cp D:/ Test");
```

I get no output, nor errors.
Can someone help me whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You  need to get `InputStream` out of the `Process` and read the input.